# WebStorm Emmet is too slow and not opened suggestion list like VSCode

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, emmet

Recently I've used WebStorm for creating React apps and I have a problem with the Emmet: it is too slow to open and you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> to open the suggestions. I did all the modifications in the WebStorm main settings and nothing improved.

Can anyone help with this? All settings are in ideal situations and I tried a lot of ways.

[image]

Even the unnecessary frameworks and library in live template is unchecked, like Vue and Angular. Just JS, HTML, CSS and React.

Comment: I suggest you provide more context: 1) in what kind of file it does not work ( an example with screenshot is very welcome), 2) what it shows and what you want to see instead etc. 3) Does it work OK in plain `.css` or `.html` files? 4) Is code completion popup shows up automatically at all anywhere? If not -- show your settings for that. **P.S.** if you know the abbreviation, you can just type it and press `Tab` (the default expand key) to have the snipped inserted in that place.